# Marionette with ES2015 babel preset dont work

Tags: javascript, marionette, babeljs, ecmascript-6

I am using Webpack with babel-loader, what have preset `es2015`, and i see this trouble: when including Marionette (v.2.4.3) `es2015` preset change `this` agrument in [/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:26](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js#L26) to `undefined` instead `this`. But this argument take `root` variable ([line 10](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js#L10)) and he see, what argument is `undefined` (not `this`) and output error.

I see, what in `es2015` preset including `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`, what include `babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode`, which response for strict mode and close es6 modules.

I tried to modify `es2015` plugin, changing `require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs")` to `[require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"), {"strict": false}]`, but this step don't help me to solve problem.

Who know, this problem with Marionette, or `es2015` preset in `babel-loader`, or with me, and how fix it?

Comment: You should only be running `babel-loader` on your own code. Unless you know what you're doing, you should exclude all library code from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem. My solution is allow top level this in modules-commonjs.

In `babel-preset-es2015` change `require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs")` to `[require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"), { allowTopLevelThis: true }]`